# How to make pnpm use symlinks for a global directory?

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, pnpm

I started using [pnpm](https://pnpm.js.org/) for my Electron project because it is faster than `npm` or `yarn`. As far as I can see it creates all modules first in `project/node_modules/.pnpm` and all packages in `project/node_modules` refer to a module inside the `.pnpm` directory.

This is already an improvement, but is there a way to put `.pnpm` outside?

At the moment my Gitlab runner deletes `node_modules` and the containing `.pnpm` directory every pipeline. In that case it would have a global project node_modules directory I could keep over many pipelines. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `node_modules/.pnpm` directory is called the virtual store directory. It is possible to change its location by setting the [virtual-store-dir](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#virtual-store-dir) setting.

Files inside the virtual store directory are just hard links to the content-addressable store. I don't think you need to cache the contents of this directory. You need to cache the global store (the content-addressable store) instead. The global store is located at `~/.pnpm-store` by default. Its location can be changed via the [store-dir](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#store-dir) setting.

Comment: Hello there ! I'm currently working on a CI config for a TS monorepo in my company, and I got that we needed to cache the `pnpm-store` folder & not the `node_modules` one. We're using Gitlab CI & I was wondering if the jobs triggered after the install one needed to do a `pnpm install` previous to their duty, with the cache that has been recovered from the install job. At least that's my understanding & that's what I'm doing on a side project. Can you confirm it's a correct way for caching the install ? P.S : our cache key is the lockfile